# iOS/Safari traffic in Jmeter - how to implement with WebDriver for Safari?

Tags: mobile, safari, jmeter, performance-testing, client-side

1. How is it possible to implement WebDriver for Safari in Jmeter (client-side)?
2. What workaround should be used instead of set up a path to WebDriver (because there is no safari driver path like for Chrome web driver)?
3. I'm confusing that there are no specific "jp@gc - Driver Config" for Safari in JMeter. - Will this absence affect tests or not and why?

Answer (score 0):

By using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) you are not emulating traffic, you're launching a **real browser** on the real mobile device (or simulator) and automating this browser using Selenium API. This is mainly used for automated testing of websites functionality.

If you need to simulate a lot of mobile users concurrently accessing your website - just go for normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. The only thing which indicates mobile Safari is its [User-Agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) which can be added to requests using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

[image]

More information:

- [iOS User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/ios/)
- [The latest user agents for Safari](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/safari)

Comment: Dmitri T, yes, it works in this way for server-side. Thank you for your notes to code with Chrome WebDriver! May be, I was not clear in my current question: if I need to test client-side with another specific browser - Safari, what changes should be done in code for client-side? Especially, regarding points 2. and 3.? Could you give any advice for Safari specifics with WebDriver, please?